# SOQL - Using like when name has "%"

Tags: soql

I have the following code:

```
String queryText = userInput.toLowerCase() + '%';
return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE : queryText];
```

And the user entered the text "G" and get results such as "George", "Google", "Game", etc etc. That works fine.

My issue is, if the user input is "%" and lets say I have an account named "%xyz", I won't get it as a result.

How can I escape the user's input here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [SOQL and SOSL Reference page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm),

You can use escape sequences to search for those characters.
To escape `%`, you should use `\%`.

The example below, taken from the above page,

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Ter\%%'
    Select all accounts whose name begins with the four character sequence 'Ter%'
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't manage to find that page :X